# Can I upgrade gnome while keeping my current kernel?

Tags: wireless, gnome, kernel

I have old HTC Shift UMPC. I have a problem with Marvell sd8686 wireless driver. It only works under some version of ubuntu. I want to upgrade my Desktop environment (gnome) to a better one. How can I do it?

Comment: Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll notice only supported releases of Ubuntu and flavors are on-topic for this site.

Comment: @guiverc Changed it.

Comment: Ubuntu Core 20 (*yy* releases of Ubuntu are *snap* only and different products to the *yy.mm* or *deb* based releases) uses a snap version of GNOME, so it'll run on releases of Ubuntu from 16.04 LTS up; however that's likely not what you meant (Ubuntu Core 20 is a different system to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS).  Also, Ubuntu 18.04 LTS using the HWE kernel is using the same identical kernel stack as Ubuntu 20.04 LTS using the GA kernel stack?   Which kernel stack are using you using?

Comment: GNOME is the desktop, which needs to match up with the toolkits & software stack underneath (GTK), just like application programs.  The original release you said you were using was GTK 2.22, where as GNOME used in 20.04 LTS is 3.36 and relies on GTK 3.36, so all applications installed need to be compatible with that software stack.  Ubuntu keeps them in in sync by using releases (18.04, 18.10, 19.04, 20.04 etc) and mixing them all up requires a lot of work, and opens you up to security holes, let alone maintenance (all security backporting will now be on you!) so is not recommended.

Comment: Also note LTS release have two kernel stacks (*offered/choices*), so if you're using the HWE of one LTS release, that is actually the GA kernel stack of the following/subsequent LTS release, ie. my prior comment about 18.04 HWE being identical kernel stack (including graphics) as the 20.04 using the GA stack.  That would allow the kernel to remain the same, allowing *kernel modules* (*drivers*) to be identical in the subsequent LTS release (assuming HWE followed by GA)